# Always showing tooltip on all columns in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's a column chart - https://jsfiddle.net/kx8qqh2e/

When you hover on a column, it shows a nice tooltip. I want to show the tooltips on all the columns at all times without having the user to hover over them. How can I achieve this?

```
var chart_data;
    chart_data = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
        backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB',
        plotBackgroundColor: '#FBFBFB'
      },
      title: {
        text: '<b>Category-Wise APF</b>',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
          color: '#454545',
          fontSize: '14px'
        },
        y: 13
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
      },
      yAxis: {
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: '',
        gridLineColor: '#EFEFEF'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b>'
      },
      series: [
        {
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [
            {
              name: 'Sports & Fitness',
              y: 1.34,
              color: '#2E91A4'
            }, {
              name: 'Fashion Apparels',
              y: 1.29,
              color: '#3196A5'
            }, {
              name: 'Women\'s Clothing',
              y: 1.24,
              color: '#2F9BA6'
            }, {
              name: 'Footwear',
              y: 1.23,
              color: '#319FA7'
            }, {
              name: 'Clothing & Apparels',
              y: 1.21,
              color: '#34A3A8'
            }, {
              name: 'Audio Equipments',
              y: 1.20,
              color: '#36A3A8'
            }, {
              name: 'Home Decor',
              y: 1.13,
              color: '#38ADAA'
            }, {
              name: 'Health & Personal Care',
              y: 1.12,
              color: '#38B1AB'
            }, {
              name: 'Mobile Accessories',
              y: 1.12,
              color: '#39B7AB'
            }, {
              name: 'Computer Accessories',
              y: 1.11,
              color: '#3DBBAD'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    $('#categorywise-apf-graph').highcharts(chart_data);
```

Comment: You can use `labels` but it requires that you define each label by hand with the style and position for each label. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx8qqh2e/3/) answers your question.

The effect you want was achieved by using the `plotOptions`[API link here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels) directive in highcharts.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chart_data;
  chart_data = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB',
      plotBackgroundColor: '#FBFBFB'
    },
    title: {
      text: '<b>Category-Wise APF</b>',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      useHTML: true,
      style: {
        color: '#454545',
        fontSize: '14px'
      },
      y: 13
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: '',
      gridLineColor: '#EFEFEF'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'left',
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'Sports & Fitness',
        y: 1.34,
        color: '#2E91A4'
      }, {
        name: 'Fashion Apparels',
        y: 1.29,
        color: '#3196A5'
      }, {
        name: 'Women\'s Clothing',
        y: 1.24,
        color: '#2F9BA6'
      }, {
        name: 'Footwear',
        y: 1.23,
        color: '#319FA7'
      }, {
        name: 'Clothing & Apparels',
        y: 1.21,
        color: '#34A3A8'
      }, {
        name: 'Audio Equipments',
        y: 1.20,
        color: '#36A3A8'
      }, {
        name: 'Home Decor',
        y: 1.13,
        color: '#38ADAA'
      }, {
        name: 'Health & Personal Care',
        y: 1.12,
        color: '#38B1AB'
      }, {
        name: 'Mobile Accessories',
        y: 1.12,
        color: '#39B7AB'
      }, {
        name: 'Computer Accessories',
        y: 1.11,
        color: '#3DBBAD'
      }]
    }]
  };
  $('#categorywise-apf-graph').highcharts(chart_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>



<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="categorywise-apf-graph"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is something closer to what I want. Is there a way to show the names as well?

Comment: you can add in a `{point.name}` in the `format` option for the `dataLabels` directive. I have to warn you though, since it is very narrow there's going to be a huge set of overlap and it does not look good. [Please check the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.borderWidth) as that is what I am doing (I've never used highcharts before)

Answer (score 11):

**For the sake of clarity and posterity:**

You can turn off the standard `tooltip`, and use the `dataLabels` to accomplish your goal.

```
tooltip: { 
  enabled: false,
  crosshairs: true
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

By default, a small label with the y value of the column will be placed above the column.

You can use the extensive configuration options, and the `formatter` function, to customize this label in a wide variety of ways, making it more like the standard `tooltip`

Example of a highly customized version of the `dataLabel`:

**Code:**

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: { 
      enabled: true, 
      inside: false,
      overflow: 'none',
      crop: true,
      shape: 'callout',
      backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)',
      borderWidth: .5,
      borderRadius: 5,
      y: -10,
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textShadow: 'none'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return '<strong>'+this.series.name+'</strong>'
                    +'<br/>Group: <strong>'+ this.x+'</strong>'
              +'<br/>Value: <strong>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)+'</strong>';
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/5t50dLow/

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]

**[{ EDIT --**

And, since having big labels like this can be distracting when what you really want to do is just see the data plotted, here's a version with a button to toggle the visibility of the labels:

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/5t50dLow/4/

Code:

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle Data Labels</button>
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  var enabled = chart.series[0].options.dataLabels.enabled;
  console.log(enabled);
  chart.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { enabled: !enabled }});
});
```

**-- /EDIT }]**